# What is the reason for the failure of the persist in doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

What is the reason for the failure of the persist in doctrine? (spl_object_id returns exists oid in doctrine)
I want insert 3 objects in loop. The first two are added.

`$this->entityManager->getUnitOfWork()->getScheduledEntityInsertions() //But third object is empty after persist`

Loop

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
   if ($item instanceof Item) {
      $orderItem =  OrderItem::createFromItem($order->getId(), $item);
      $this->entityManager->persist($orderItem);
      $this->entityManager->flush();
   }
}
```

Class (short version)

```
use App\Service\Payments\Model\Item;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * OrderItem
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="order_item")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OrderItem
{
    private $id;
    private $orderId;
    private $productId;
    private $quantity;
    private $price;

    public static function createFromItem(int $orderId, Item $item): OrderItem
    {
            $orderItem = new self();
            $orderItem->orderId = $orderId;
            $orderItem->productId = $item->getProductId();
            $orderItem->price = $item->getPriceWithoutDiscount() ?? $item->getPrice();
            $orderItem->quantity = $item->getQuantity();
            return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just read this manual) https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.15/reference/batch-processing.html